# "Could not find appcompat-v7.aar" on Gradle build after running tns update

Tags: android, gradle, nativescript, nativescript-vue

### Summarize the problem

**When did this start to happen?**

I wanted to update ListPicker text-color value, so I followed these steps ([more info](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/7860#issuecomment-630219496)):

- Run `sdkmanager --update`;
- Update Android SDK version in app.gradle;
- Nuke node_modules;
- Run `npm install`;
- Run `tns update`;
- Run `tns platform remove android`;
- Run `tns run android`.

**Error messages**

Below is a summary of the build output.

```
Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
nativescript-plugin-firebase: building for same environment, not forcing prepare.
Project successfully prepared (android)
Configure firebase
Copy C:\Users\Hp\Documents\BitBucket\ayneh-mobile-app\app\App_Resources\Android\google-services.json to C:\Users\Hp\Documents\BitBucket\ayneh-mobile-app\platforms\android\app\google-services.json.
Building project...
Gradle build...
     + setting applicationId
     + applying user-defined configuration from C:\Users\Hp\Documents\BitBucket\ayneh-mobile-app\app\App_Resources\Android\app.gradle
     Applying settings from C:\Users\Hp\Documents\BitBucket\ayneh-mobile-app\app\App_Resources\Android\settings.json
     + using android X library androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
     + adding nativescript runtime package dependency: nativescript-optimized-with-inspector
[...]
Build file 'C:\Users\Hp\Documents\BitBucket\ayneh-mobile-app\platforms\android\app\build.gradle' line: 598
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Could not find appcompat-v7.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha05).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/appcompat/appcompat/1.1.0-alpha05/appcompat-v7-1.1.0-alpha05.aar
```

### Share some code

app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 26
    generatedDensities = []
  }
  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
}

def settingsGradlePath

if(project.hasProperty("appResourcesPath")){
    settingsGradlePath = "$project.appResourcesPath/Android/settings.gradle";
} else {
    settingsGradlePath = "$rootDir/../../app/App_Resources/Android/settings.gradle";
}

def settingsGradleFile = new File(settingsGradlePath);

if(settingsGradleFile.exists())
{
    apply from: settingsGradleFile;
}
```

platforms/android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

    def initialize = { ->
        def userDir = "${rootProject.projectDir}/../.."
        apply from: "$rootDir/gradle-helpers/user_properties_reader.gradle"
        apply from: "$rootDir/gradle-helpers/paths.gradle"
        rootProject.ext.userDefinedGradleProperties = getUserProperties("${getAppResourcesPath(userDir)}/Android")
    }
    initialize()

    def computeKotlinVersion = { -> project.hasProperty("kotlinVersion") ? kotlinVersion : "1.3.41"
    }
    def kotlinVersion = computeKotlinVersion()

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.fabric.io/public" }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools" }
 }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1"
 }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    beforeEvaluate { project ->
        if (rootProject.hasProperty("userDefinedGradleProperties")) {
            rootProject.ext.userDefinedGradleProperties.each { entry ->
                def propertyName = entry.getKey()
                def propertyValue = entry.getValue()
                project.ext.set(propertyName, propertyValue)
            }
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### Describe what you've tried

1. Change SDK version in app.gradle.
2. Add `mavenCentral()` to `buildscript`'s `repositories` in build.gradle.
3. Update Android Studio.
4. `tns platform remove android`

Comment: please share build.gradle

Comment: @JavadDehban Sure.